# ng-bootstrap typeahead display spinner when performing search

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

On my project, ng-bootstrap is used to create a typeahead in order to search for users.
A spinner is displayed when the search is still going.
The typeahead performs a search when:

1. The user enters some text in the field
2. The user clicks on the field
3. The field gains focus

Everything is almost perfect except for one detail that I can't manage to fix. When entering text, if the search is still going, typing additionnal text makes the spinner disappear even though the new search will be performing.

This is due to the statement in the finalize of the first subscription being run after the first tap statement of the second subscription.

All my code is inspired by: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples

```html
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed"
       [formControl]="formControl"
       (selectItem)="onSelectMember($event)"
       [ngbTypeahead]="search"
       [resultFormatter]="formatMember"
       (focus)="focus$.next($any($event).target.value)"
       (click)="click$.next($any($event).target.value)"
       #instance="ngbTypeahead"
       [placeholder]="'MEMBERS.TYPEAHEAD.PLACEHOLDER' | translate" />
<span *ngIf="searching"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> {{'MEMBERS.TYPEAHEAD.SEARCHING' | translate}}</span>
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">{{'MEMBERS.TYPEAHEAD.NORESULTS' | translate}}</div>
```

```js
import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbTypeahead } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { merge, Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter, finalize, map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MemberService } from '../../@core/data';
import { Member } from '../../@core/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'de-member-type-ahead',
  templateUrl: './member-type-ahead.component.html',
})
export class MemberTypeAheadComponent {
  @Input() formControl: AbstractControl;
  @Input() searchRegisteredMembers: boolean = true;
  @Input() maxResults: number = 10;

  @ViewChild('instance', {static: true}) instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  searching = false;
  searchFailed = false;

  constructor(private memberService: MemberService) {
  }

  formatMember = (result: Member) => {
    return result.getFullName() + ' (' + result.getEmail() + ')';
  }

  onSelectMember(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.formControl.patchValue(event.item);
  }

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    this.getSearchObservable(text$).pipe(
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      switchMap(term =>
        this.memberService.searchByNameAndEmail(term, this.searchRegisteredMembers).pipe(
          tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
          map(result => result.slice(0, this.maxResults)),
          catchError(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return of([]);
          }),
          finalize(() => this.searching = false)),
      ),
      tap(() => this.searching = false),
    )


  private getSearchObservable = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    );

    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(
      filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()),
      filter(() => !this.searching),
    );

    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$.pipe(
      filter(() => !this.searching),
    );

    return merge(debouncedText$, clicksWithClosedPopup$, inputFocus$);
  }
}
```

I've also reproduced this behaviour by adapting the official Wikipedia example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwxzjr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftypeahead-http.ts
(This works best by disabling cache and throttling your connection rate)

Do you have any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: https://angular-rwxzjr-s3meyx.stackblitz.io is that better? It's strange to me why you're debouncing twice, it can cause an extra delay. But the `search` method/function went from inside of the `switchMap` right before we make an API call, turn searching on. Inside of the tap after the API call, turn searching off and inside of the catch as well, turn searching off.

Comment: Same as the answer from AliF50:
If I cancel a request that is being processed (by leaving the field for example), the spinner does not disappear ;)
This is due to your removing the finalize statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that got modified:

```
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    this.getSearchObservable(text$).pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => {
        this.searching = true;
        return this._service.search(term).pipe(
          tap(() => { 
            this.searching = false;
            this.searchFailed = false; 
          }),
          catchError(() => {
            this.searching = false;
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return of([]);
          }))
      }),
    )
  
  private getSearchObservable = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(
      // debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    );

    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(
      filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()),
      filter(() => !this.searching),
    );

    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$.pipe(
      filter(() => !this.searching),
    );

    return merge(debouncedText$, clicksWithClosedPopup$, inputFocus$);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
However, this does not work perfectly. If I cancel a request that is being processed (by leaving the field for example), the spinner does not disappear ;)
This is due to your removing the finalize statement.